# Django: images not loading instead of alternative text

Tags: python, django, rss

I tried to display media thumbnails from other news website on my django website homepage by using feedparser, but the image is not loading, instead the alternative displayed:
[this is my current homepage looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xrlP.jpg)

homepage.html:

```
<div class="col-md-2 my-auto">
 <img
  src="{{ post.image.url }}"
  class="img-fluid ml-3 my-3"
  alt="{{ post.pubdate }}"
 >
</div>
```

models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    pubdate = models.DateTimeField()
    link = models.URLField()
    image = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**startjobs.py**(this custom command file used feedparser to parse news):

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def save_new_posts(feed):
    feed_title = feed.channel.title
    feed_image = feed.channel.image['href'][0]

    for item in feed.entries:
        if not Post.objects.filter(link=item.link).exists():
            post = Post(
                title=item.title,
                description=item.description,
                pubdate=parser.parse(item.published),
                link=item.link,
                image=feed_image,
            )
            post.save()

def fetch_fox_posts():
    _feed = feedparser.parse("http://feeds.foxnews.com/foxnews/latest")
    save_new_posts(_feed)

def fetch_nbc_posts():
    _feed = feedparser.parse("https://feeds.nbcnews.com/nbcnews/public/news")
    save_new_posts(_feed)

def delete_old_job_executions(max_age=604_800):
    DjangoJobExecution.objects.delete_old_job_executions(max_age)
```

views.py:

```
class HomePage(ListView):
    template_name = "homepage.html"
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 10
    ordering = ['pubdate']

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["posts"] = Post.objects.filter().order_by("-pubdate")[
            :10
        ]
        return context
```

main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", include("news.urls")),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'), name='homepage'),
]
```

Not sure why the image is not displayed instead of alternative text, any help would be appreciated

Comment: UrlFields don't have a `url` property, accessing the field should return the stored URL - `{{ post.image }}`

Comment: @IainShelvington Can you please explain which url property should be added?

Comment: Just use `post.image` like in my first comment, not `post.image.url`

Comment: @IainShelvington Unfortunately the images are still not loading after I changed `post.image.url` to `post.image`, and the command prompt reported `GET /h HTTP/1.1 404 2482` and `Not Found: /h  `. It is confusing since I only want to display the images, but the website leads to some non-existing address?

Comment: Looks like you just get the first character of the image URL here - `feed_image = feed.channel.image['href'][0]`. You probably want to get the full URL instead?